# Can I safely use controls that only have a public factory method in the WinForms designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, factory

I know I can manually edit form.designer.cs to call the factory method in place of the inaccessible constructor it inserts when I pull the control from the toolbar.  But since VS rewrites the designer file at whim I don't want to do something that's going to end up breaking when the form designer does it's rewrite thing.

```
//VS Generated code
this.myControl1 = new Foo.Bar.Controls.MyControl();

//Factory replacement 
this.myControl1 = Solution.Project.ClassFactory.CreateMyControl();
```

Comment: When do you want this "factory method" to be called? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @GerrieSchenck  In the forms designer.cs file.  So I can easily swap out all instances of MyControl for MyControlExCustomerN app wide if needed. (NDA requirements force separating the customer specific functionality from the main codebase, so I need to use derived classes instead of toggling features on/off using flags of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyControlFactoryConverter))]
public class MyControl : Control {
    public string Parameter { get; private set; }
    public MyControl() { }
    public MyControl(string parameter) {
        Parameter = parameter;
    }
}
public static class MyControlFactory {
    public static MyControl CreateControl(string parameter) {
        return new MyControl(parameter);
    }
}
//
public class MyControlFactoryConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        if(destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) return true;
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        if(destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value != null) {
            MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(MyControlFactory).GetMethod("CreateControl",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            return new InstanceDescriptor(mInfo, new object[] { "Hello World" });
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Thia approach generated the following code within the designer.cs file:

```
this.myControl1 = WindowsFormsApplication3.MyControlFactory.CreateControl("Hello World");
```

Comment: I tried this and am getting hammered by "Parameter must be static" message boxes when saving a form using the control or at build time; and the only thing being put in the designer is the `private Solution.Project.Controls.MyControl myControl1;` line.  Do you have any idea where I'm slipping up?

Comment: The demonstrated approach works fine to me. Have your used the same code? Have you tried to debug these errors? Unfortunately I haven't any idea because i can't see your actual code at all. Please update your question with more details.